# How to run basic test using karma (testacular)

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I've been playing with jasmine recently in order to start incorporating tests in my projects.
All seemed to work fine until, I wanted to automate the workflow with karma (previously Karma).

In my src directory, I have simple Calculator Object with a couple of simple methods:
function Calculator() { };

var current = 0;

```
Calculator.prototype.add = function() {
if (arguments.length < 2) { 
    // we only have one arguments
    current += arguments[0];
    return current;
} else { 
    // more than one arguments
    for( var i in arguments ) 
        current += arguments[i];
    return current;
}
};

Calculator.prototype.substract = function() {
var currentValue = arguments[0];

for ( var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++ ) 
    currentValue -= arguments[i];   
return currentValue;
};

Calculator.prototype.reset = function() {
window.current = 0;
}
```

Then in my spec file, I do have the following ( all tests passes without Karma ):

var calculator = new Calculator();

```
describe('Calculator', function() {
beforeEach(function() {
    window.current = 0;
});

describe('When adding numbers', function() {
    it('should store the current value at all times', function() {
        expect(window.current).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should add numbers', function() {
        expect(window.calculator.add(5)).toEqual(5);
        expect(window.calculator.add(10)).toEqual(15);
    });

    it('should add any number of numbers', function() {
        expect(calculator.add(1, 2, 3)).toEqual(6);
        expect(calculator.add(1, 2)).toEqual(9);
    })
});

describe('When substracting numbers', function() {
    it('should substract any number of numbers', function() {
        expect(calculator.substract(5, 3)).toEqual(2);
    });
});

it('should reset the current value back to zero', function() {
    window.current = 20;
    calculator.reset();

    expect(window.current).toEqual(0);

    calculator.add(5);
    calculator.add(20);
    expect(window.current).toEqual(25);

    calculator.reset();
    expect(window.current).toEqual(0);
});
});
```

When I run karma start, I get the following: 
Chrome 28.0 (Mac) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Calculator is not defined
    at /Users/roland/learning/jasmine/jasmine-standalone-1.3.1/spec/calculator_spec.js:1

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're not loading the file that has `Calculator` or perhaps it's being loaded after the spec file. In your Karma configuration file, you'll want to do  something like this:

```
files = [
  'path/to/calculator.js',
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,   
  'path/to/calculator_spec.js'
];
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! I was just watching the spec folder! thanks!